# D3JS dynamically accessing elements of an Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a problem when trying to reference an array in a dynamic way. I won't always know before hand which field my user will select so I want to make a dynamic selection into the array. I was hoping I could store the field in a variable, and then use this variable to specify which field I want from the array.

I have made a simple example to illustrate my problem.

If I access the array like this:

```
console.log('static: ' + nested_data[0].values[0].cat);
```

Then in returns 'a' which is what I expected, however if I do:

```
console.log('dynamic :' + nested_data[0].values[0].label);
```

where label is a variable, then I get 'undefined'.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

```
// Some Sample data
var data = [
{ value: 01, cat:'a'},
{ value: 40, cat:'a'},
{ value: 80, cat:'b'},
{ value: 120, cat:'b'}
];

//Nest the data on 'cat'
var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.cat; })
.entries(data);

//Print the value of the data[0].values[0].cat
console.log('static: ' + nested_data[0].values[0].cat); 

//Dynamic, create a variable to hold the parameter I want to refrence
var label = 'cat';
//Pass the variable to the array
console.log('dynamic :' + nested_data[0].values[0].label);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation:

```
console.log('dynamic :' + nested_data[0].values[0][label]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's so obvious now! Thanks again.